# How can I make a sprite to do a visible moving from a position to a mouse click in monogame?

Tags: c#, mouseevent, sprite, monogame

I am making a fireball, which is moving to a mouse clicked position.
The fireball sprite is already moving to the postion, but I can't see the fireball fly.
I want to see, that the fireball "flys" to the postion?

here is my monogame code, written in c#

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
                Exit();

            // TODO: Add your update logic here
            var CurrentMouseState = Mouse.GetState();
            PreviousMouseState = CurrentMouseState;
            if (CurrentMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                ballPosition = new Vector2(CurrentMouseState.X, CurrentMouseState.Y);

            }

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }
```

Could anybody help me?
I didn't find help in other questions.

Answer (score 1):

So far the ball is moving instantly to the position to the mouse. but now it needs to move on it's own to the mouse position.

Assuming with 'flying towards the mouse', you mean moving in a straight line to the mouse position. You can try using `Vector2.Normalize` to decide in which direction and angle it needs to move to the mouse.

Try out the answer found here: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/7757/96707